# Session destroy event with JTA Transaction

Tags: spring, session, jboss

I am working on JBOSS application and I am facing issue for loggin sessionTimeout event

I want to make JTA transaction once the session is expire.

My code is as follow

**spring.xml**

...

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" >
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="msg" class="com.Message">
    ....
</bean>
```

...

**web.xml**

...

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.demo.MySessionListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

...

**Class File**

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());
        Message msg = (Message)ctx.getBean("msg");
        msg.save();    //    throws error org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException
    }

}
```

I found that  All the JTA operation must be done in session, But in this case how can I achieve this ? Because I want to perform JTA transaction because of the session expiration event.

Let me know if anyone have solve this problem even before.

Thanks

**StackTrace**

```
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSession.removeAttributeInternal(ClusteredSession.java:1292)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSession.expire(ClusteredSession.java:844)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSession.expire(ClusteredSession.java:740)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSession.isValid(ClusteredSession.java:720)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSession.isValid(ClusteredSession.java:685)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.JBossCacheManager.processExpires(JBossCacheManager.java:1236)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.JBossManager.backgroundProcess(JBossManager.java:817)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.JBossCacheManager.backgroundProcess(JBossCacheManager.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workContext': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message,your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(Cglib2AopProxy.java:661)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:611)
    at com.ideas.carparkpro.commons.bean.CproWorkContext$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ef8de176.getDataSource()
    at com.ideas.carparkpro.core.util.UserRoutingDataSource.determineCurrentLookupKey(UserRoutingDataSource.java:103)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message,your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:285)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: You are confused between the `HttpSession` and hibernate session. Those are different things. Post the full stack trace to get more help. Also you don't do anything with JTA as you are using the plain `HibernateTransactionManager` and not a `JtaTransactionManager` so you aren't using JTA.

Comment: Please have a look the stacktrace, Session timeout doest have any request from client

Comment: You are tryin to use a session scoped object outside of an active http request, that is never going to work. IMHO yo have something wrong in your `UserRoutingDataSource` that shouldn't be a session scoped proxy imho.

Comment: Ok, Then how can I achieve this things to happens, I want to log client logout event in database using Spring and JBOSS ?

Comment: Hi All,
This Guy has the same Issue please have a look : http://hadoop43.blogspot.in/2015/03/session-destroy-event-with-jta.html